# Xcode5 how to select from two provisioning profiles with same name?

Tags: xcode5, provisioning-profile

Xcode5 generates multiple profiles with identical name, which you - as the developer - are not allowed to name. As soon as you're a member of more than one team (e.g. different teams within your organization, or different projects you work on), you'll have one:

"iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *"

...per team.

But it seems no-one at Apple thought to test what happens with this: it breaks Xcode5's profile selector. If you have more than one profile with the same name, Xcode5 can only "see" the newest one. Even though they are for different teams, and are *not* compatible (devices authorized for one are not authorized for the other - that 100 devices per account limit, for instance).

There's a workaround: you can use iPCU to look through all your profiles (with the same name :( ) and manually copy/paste their ID into Xcode5's "Other" menu, and keep rebuilding until one of them works. ... but that's slow and error-prone.

Is there another way? Is it possible to locally rename a Provisioning Profile, for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that's been fixed in Xcode 5.1

So ... upgrade :)